# Square image with full height (FF/Safari)

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I’m looking to implement a full height (no-scroll) layout which contains a square image.
Depending on the available height of the container the image should scale accordingly in width.

[image]

So far I’ve attempted to implement the layout using both — floats and flexbox — but any solution (including anything responded to similar questions here) either leads to an overlap between image/container and the additional content to the right or doesn’t calculate 100% as intended (e.g. by including the height of the header).

My most recent attempt looks like this:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #D8D8D8;
}

.header {
  background: #FF9C9C;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  border: 1px solid #7100FF;
  height: 100%; 
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.aside {
  background: #B6F0C7;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Card image">
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
      <p>Other content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s0846ozy/

*It’s been a few years since I have worked with CSS. Looking forward to having a rather obvious flaw in my approach pointed out. Thanks!*

**EDIT**:

1. It seems this issue is browser-specific. I’m using the latest Firefox.
2. `object-fit` won't solve the issue as far as I can tell and is something I’ve already explored.
3. I’ve added a JSFiddle for easier experimentation.

---

**Chrome** (expected):
[image]

**Firefox** (actual):
[image]

Comment: your code works fine on chrome

Comment: Thanks Temani, that's insightful and a bit frustrating as I’m using FF.

Comment: I was able to confirm that my code indeed works on Chrome but not Safari or FF. All on Mac.

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

for preserving the aspect-ratio!!

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, this is one of the many things I’ve tried but unfortunately this approach requires a square container to exist, which is not the case in my example. My use case is a bit more complicated as described and I’m using the image to “keep a square space open” for an absolutely positioned object. If you feel like I misunderstood you I’d very much appreciate an example.

Comment: @polarblau use CSS's  grid with my code.It will work then

Comment: CSS Grid is an interesting suggestion and something I haven't tried yet. Will give this a go. Thanks!

Comment: I did give it a try but it's not solving the problem, unfortunately. Browser inconsistency remains.